# Ruby code format - What is the meaning of ruby code format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does this mean in Ruby ? Why are they assigning same value to existing hash value ?

```
Proc.new { |message|
   {
      'field1' => message.field1,
      'field2' => message.field2.to_s,
      'field3' => message.field3,,
      'field4' => message.field4.to_s,,
   }
}
```

What is the meaning of above structure ? Why same value has been assigned in hash ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Why same value has been assigned in hash". They are not the same values? 2 of them are converted to strings, which may be useful for certain purposes if you want to work with a hash of only string values.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the code above has 2 syntax errors: the first `,,` should be `,` and the second `,,` shouldn't be there.

This code creates a `proc` that takes as an argument an object that responds to `.field1`, `.field2`, `.field3`, `.field4`.  It returns a `Hash` that has 4 fields in it, converting `field2` and `field4` to strings.

So, the input could be something like an `OpenStruct` (but doesn't have to be; it just has to respond to the 4 method calls above):

```
foo = OpenStruct.new
foo.field1 = 'hi'
foo.field2 = 123
foo.field3 = 'bar'
foo.field4 = 456
```

Now passing that parameter to the `Proc` returns:

```
{"field1"=>"hi", "field2"=>"123", "field3"=>"bar", "field4"=>"456"}
```

I can't say WHY the code does this.